# Count pending $q promises in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, q, angular-promise

I'm working on a complex angularjs app. Complex meaning single view can have several different data sources being queried from different places of the code, e.g. page-part controller or directive controller. Sometimes some of these requests can take longer time to resolve, thus leaving the view in somewhat invalid state.
I would like to be able to display some sort of "data loading" banner and disable user interaction with view until all promises have resolved. This works with simple screens using $q.all() function.
But, the way app is being structured is more business logic centric, rather than data-source centric. So for a more complicated screen there will be no single place where all promises made are naturally accessible. Creating such a place in the code seems cumbersome.

I have come up with this solution:

```
angular.module('myApp').service('qConfigurer', function ($q) {
    var pending = 0;
    var origDefer = $q.defer;

    $q.defer = function() {
        pending++;
        var result = origDefer.apply(arguments);

        var origResolve = result.resolve;
        var origReject = result.reject;

        result.resolve = function() {
            pending--;
            return origResolve.apply(arguments);
        };

        result.reject = function() {
            pending--;
            return origReject.apply(arguments);
        };

        return result;
    };

    $q.pending = function() {
        return pending;
    };

    return {};
});
```

is there less *hacky* to achieve the same?

Comment: Why is this solution hacky?

Comment: overriding methods of system service looks hacky.

Comment: I don't see the problem, although you might consider using `$provide.decorator` to extend $q with your service

Comment: @MarcKline, yes decorator approach looks better.

Comment: If you are looking for specifically http requests $http has a property pendingRequests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're doing is modifying the global state, and hacking changes into `$q`, this sort of AOP can create problems with third party modules plugins rather easily and I believe it is dangerous, it does not let you scope what changes yourself, not to mention the speed penalty.

#### What I think is better

In my opinion, you'd really want is a way to do resource management, a sort of `try(resource)` from Java, `using(` from C# or `with` from Python. Unfortunately, the only promise implementation that has this is Bluebird, and we're using $q here, so let's make one :)

So, we want a function that scopes on a promise, and no matter what the result turns to be, reduces one from a counter - in our case, our resource forms a [semaphore](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_%28programming%29).

```
function loading(fn){  // takes a function that returns a promise, put in a service
      var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,1);
      return $q.when().then(function(){
          loading.counter++; // signal the scope somehow, either by having the counter
                             // on the scope and accepting it as a param, by a watcher or
                             // with an emit
      }).then(function(){
          return fn.apply(null, args); // can add context param if you want for `this`
      }).finally(function(){
          loading.counter--; // signal just like with the above
      });
}
loading.counter = 0;
```

Then, usage becomes:

```
 // you can use it like this
 loading(function(){
     return myService.apiCall(...);
 }).then(function(result){
      $scope.a = result;
 });
 // or like this
 loading(myService.apiCall,...).then(function(result){
     $scope.b = result;
 });
```

If you put your showing/hiding logic, or an event hook, or a scope variable or an input parameter in your loading function (I'm leaving this for personal preference, just do *something* when it hits zero, and when it hits one) - it will show/hide the loading screen.

Comment: interesting approach, will take a look.